# Having an issue with method function

Tags: java, arrays, debugging, sorting

So the basic overall function of the code is to take in the the array and sort in ascending order. I get no errors within my code but I believe something is wrong. I have made some test cases and some have failed and I have a feeling in the `recursivesort` method I am doing something wrong. I have done multiple debugging walk through and just cant find where is the problem?

```
public class RecursiveSorter {

    private int[] sortedArray;
    private int[] array;

    public RecursiveSorter() {
        array = new int[1];
    }

    public RecursiveSorter(int[] a) {
        array = a;
    }

    public void setArray(int[] a) {
        array = a;
    }

    public int[] getSortedArray() {
        return sortedArray;
    }

    public int[] getOriginalArray() {
        return array;
    }

    public int[] sort() {
        sortedArray = array;
        recursiveSort(sortedArray.length - 1); 
        return sortedArray;
    }

    public int[] recursiveSort(int endIndex) {
        if (endIndex >= 0) {
            int m = getMaxIndex(endIndex, sortedArray);
            swap(m, endIndex, sortedArray);
            recursiveSort(endIndex-1);
        }
        return sortedArray;
    }

    public int getMaxIndex(int endIndex, int[] a) {
        int max = a[0];
        int maxIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < endIndex; i++) {
            if (a[i] > max) {  
                max = a[i];
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return maxIndex;
    }

    public void swap(int src, int dest, int[] a) {
        int temp = a[dest];
        a[dest] = src;
        a[src] = temp;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Original: " + prettyPrint(getOriginalArray()) + "\n" +
               "Sorted:   " + prettyPrint(getSortedArray());
    }

    private String prettyPrint(int[] a) {
        String s = "";
        for (int i : a)
            s += i + " ";
        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Automate running, but not testing
        int[] array = {5, 67, 12, 20};
        RecursiveSorter s = new RecursiveSorter(array);
        s.sort();
        System.out.println(s); // uses Sorter.toString
    }
}
```

Comment: _" I believe something is wrong"_ - Would you care to be a little more specific?

Comment: @Keppil yea when I do a walkthrough the values are not matching up to what they should be which is what led me to think that method has an error in it which I can not seem to address.

Comment: Is this right? `sortedArray = array;` You are creating a second reference to the same array.

Comment: @ABoschman just noticed that, my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap method has error:

```
a[dest] = src;
```

Should be:

```
a[dest] = a[src];
```

Also this line will not copy array, so you have the `array` and `sortedArray` referencing same array object.

```
sortedArray = array;
```

Replace it with:

```
sortedArray = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
```

Also in method `getMaxIndex` is missing equals sign:

```
for (int i = 1; i < endIndex; i++) {
```

Should be:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= endIndex; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

1-you have to clone (or to copy) the array to the sortedArray.

2-The swap method was not correct.

3-The first call of the method recursiveSort should be parametrized by the last index of the array so sortedArray.length - 1.

```
public class RecursiveSorter {

    private int[] sortedArray;
    private int[] array;

    public RecursiveSorter() {
        array = new int[1];
    }

    public RecursiveSorter(int[] a) {
        array = a;
    }

    public void setArray(int[] a) {
        array = a;
    }

    public int[] getSortedArray() {
        return sortedArray;
    }

    public int[] getOriginalArray() {
        return array;
    }

    public void sort() {
        sortedArray = array.clone();
        System.out.println(this);
        recursiveSort(sortedArray.length - 1); //Should subtract by length
    }

    public void recursiveSort(int endIndex) {
        System.out.println("Sorting with param : "+endIndex);
        if (endIndex >= 0) {
            int m = getMaxIndex(endIndex, sortedArray);
            swap(m, endIndex);
            System.out.println(this);
            recursiveSort(endIndex - 1);
        }
    }

    public int getMaxIndex(int endIndex, int[] a) {
        int max = a[0];
        int maxIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= endIndex; i++) {
            if (a[i] > max) {
                max = a[i];
                maxIndex = i;
                System.out.println("Max index : " + i);
            }
        }
        return maxIndex;
    }

    public void swap(int src, int dest) {
        System.out.println("Swap : "+src+" to "+dest);
        int temp = sortedArray[dest];
        sortedArray[dest] = sortedArray[src];
        sortedArray[src] = temp;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Original: " + prettyPrint(getOriginalArray()) + "\n"
                + "Sorted:   " + prettyPrint(getSortedArray());
    }

    private String prettyPrint(int[] a) {
        String s = "";
        for (int i : a) {
            s += i + " ";
        }
        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Automate running, but not testing
        int[] array = {5, 67, 12, 20};
        RecursiveSorter s = new RecursiveSorter(array);
        s.sort();
        //System.out.println(s); // uses Sorter.toString
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks. I should have caught some of those.